# UIImageView+AFNetworking categories with UIActivityIndicatorView reference memory retain?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, afnetworking

i'm trying to implement a categories to show a `UIImageView` from a url with fading and a `UIActivityIndicatorView`, i have found something on the web and i have edited in this final version:

UIImageView+AFNetworkingLoad.m

```
@implementation UIImageView (AFNetworkingLoad)

- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage fadeInWithDuration:(CGFloat)duration withLoadIndicator:(UIActivityIndicatorView *)load_indicator {

    [load_indicator startAnimating];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
    [request addValue:@"image/*" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    __weak typeof (self) weakSelf = self;

    [self setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:placeholderImage success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
        [load_indicator stopAnimating];
        if (!request) // image was cached
            [weakSelf setImage:image];
        else
            [UIView transitionWithView:weakSelf duration:duration options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
                [weakSelf setImage:image];
            } completion:nil];
    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        [load_indicator stopAnimating];
    }];
}
```

then i use it in a custom `UITableViewCell` in this way:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
MyCell *cell = (MyCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
...
[cell.img_view setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:my_url] placeholderImage:nil fadeInWithDuration:0.3 withLoadIndicator:cell.load_img];
...
}
```

all works fine, now my question is, with this implementation passing the reference of the UIActivityIndicatorView, can i have some memory leak? or retain problem? obviously i use ARC in my iOS project...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This category should not cause a memory leak. That method passes the object into a copied block so it will be retained by that block temporarily but once the image either loads or fails to load, the blocks should be cleared out which would drop the retain count of the object back down.